# Automatically distribute select/input fields with gaps

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">   
   <div class="col">
      <select name="day" style="width: 25%;">
      ....
      </select>

      <select name="month" style="width: 50%;">
      ....
      </select>

      <select name="year" style="width: 25%;">
      ....
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row { display: table; width: 100%; }
.col { display: table-cell; width: 50%; }
```

I want the `selects` to be laid out using the full width of the parent DIV, for example:

- day should be aligned to the left
- month should be aligned center
- year should be aligned to the right

There should be a gap (of around 10px) in between these fields which should be dynamically calculated.

Answer (score 0):

How does [this look](http://jsfiddle.net/2U5e3/2/)? The use of DIVs will allow for the 10px seperation requested.

HTML:

```
<div>
     <select>
        <option>Select 1</option>
    </select>
</div><div>
     <select>
        <option>Select 1</option>
    </select>
</div><div>
     <select>
        <option>Select 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;   
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div{ 
     display:inline-block;
}
select{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
div:nth-child(1){  
    width:25%;
    padding-right:10px;
}
div:nth-child(2){  
    width:50%;
}
div:nth-child(3){  
    padding-left:10px;
    width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add multiple **DIVs**, or you might need to add more CSS.

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/QY96X/1/)

```
<div class="row">   
  <select name="day">
      <option>Sunday</option>
  </select>

  <select name="month">
      <option>January</option>
  </select>

  <select name="year">
      <option>2013</option>
  </select>
```

**CSS**

```
.row { display: table; width: 100%; }
select{
    width:30%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```